# Html with javascript in php seems to be conflicting

Tags: javascript, php, html

The code i want to get into a php statement is

```
<a href="javascript:void();"
   onclick="document.loginfrm.user.value="username";
   document.loginfrm.pass.value="password";
   document.loginfrm.submit();">login
</a>
```

So what i would normally do is just surround it with an echo and quotation marks: an then replace any quotation marks in the statement with these --> ('), so that's what i did... and for some reason it seems to misinterpret the sentence severely. Here is the code i enter in php.

```
   echo "<a href='javascript:void();'
   onclick='document.loginfrm.user.value='username';
   document.loginfrm.pass.value='password';
   document.loginfrm.submit();'>". login ."</a>";
```

And this is how the browser interprets it:

```
    <a href="javascript:void();
" onclick="document.loginfrm.user.value=" username';="" 
document.loginfrm.pass.value="password" ;="" document.loginfrm.submit();'="">
login</a>
```

So yes is there any way around displaying html within php that could get around this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, added `\`

```
    echo "<a href=\"javascript:void();\"
       onclick=\"document.loginfrm.user.value='username';
       document.loginfrm.pass.value=password';
       document.loginfrm.submit();\">login </a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not escaping your quotes. Try:

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:void();\"
onclick=\"document.loginfrm.user.value='username';
document.loginfrm.pass.value='password';
document.loginfrm.submit();\">". login ."</a>";
```

which should produce:

```
<a href="javascript:void();"
   onclick="document.loginfrm.user.value='username';
   document.loginfrm.pass.value='password';
   document.loginfrm.submit();">login
</a>
```

As you have it now, you're closing the `onclick` attribute when you hit the quote at the start of the `"username"` value, which means the browser is interpreting `username` as another attribute and it just gets more confused from there...

<sub>Edit: sorry, fixed the html, rather than the php code...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape it properly. Try

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:void();\"
   onclick=\"document.loginfrm.user.value='username';
   document.loginfrm.pass.value='password';
   document.loginfrm.submit();\">". $login ."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this..

```
<a href="javascript:void();"
   onclick="document.loginfrm.user.value='username';
   document.loginfrm.pass.value='password';
   document.loginfrm.submit();">login
</a>
```

and with php it should be

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void();"
          onclick="document.loginfrm.user.value=\"username\";
          document.loginfrm.pass.value=\"password\";
          document.loginfrm.submit();">
          login
      </a>';
```